# Determine if tree node exists

Tags: vba, vbscript, sap-gui

I am creating a macro where at some point it has to navigate through some folders and sub-folders (tree nodes with children) inside SAP

The main folder is expanded in the following code:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell").expandNode "2**000001"
```

The sub-folder I´m looking for is the following:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell").selectedNode = "251000001"
```

However this sub-folder may not exist.

I want to add an `IF` statement to check if it exists or a way to get the list of sub-folders and look for the one which has the text "Status 51".

[image]

Comment: Because of "Status 51", I'm pretty sure you're talking about one of the IDoc screens, I added a screenshot for transaction code `WE02`/`WE05`. Revert if incorrect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recognize a [`GuiTree`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/760.02/en-US?q=GuiTree+Object) control, which is of type 2 (column tree).

To determine if a given node exists, if you know its key, you could use the following function that you call this way: `If TreeNodeExistsByKey(session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell"),"251000001") Then`...

```
Function TreeNodeExistsByKey(tree,nodekey)
  On Error Resume Next
  tree.GetHierarchyLevel(nodekey)
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    result = True
  Else
    result = False
  End If
  TreeNodeExistsByKey = result
End Function
```

To get and iterate the children of a given node:

```
Set tree = session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell")
Set coll = tree.GetAllNodeKeys()
For i = 0 to coll.Length - 1
  nodekey = coll.ElementAt(i)
Next
```

To get the text of a node by its key, use the method `GetNodeTextByKey`:

```
nodeText = tree.GetNodeTextByKey(nodeKey)
```